# Why am i not getting trace logs in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hey Can somebody please help me as to why am i not getting transport level trace logs. This in my current /_cluster/settings

```
{ 
  "persistent": { 
    "xpack": { 
      "monitoring": { 
        "collection": { 
          "enabled": "true" 
        } 
      } 
    }, 
    "logger": { 
      "index": { 
        "indexing": { 
          "slowlog": "WARN" 
        }, 
        "search": { 
          "slowlog": "WARN" 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  }, 
  "transient": { 
    "cluster": { 
      "routing": { 
        "allocation": { 
          "enable": "all" 
        } 
      }, 
      "service": { 
        "slow_task_logging_threshold": "30s" 
      } 
    }, 
    "indices": { 
      "recovery": { 
        "max_bytes_per_sec": "500mb" 
      } 
    }, 
    "logger": { 
      "_root": "WARN", 
      "index": { 
        "indexing": { 
          "slowlog": "WARN" 
        }, 
        "search": { 
          "slowlog": "WARN" 
        } 
      }, 
      "org": { 
        "elasticsearch": { 
          "TransportService": { 
            "tracer": "TRACE" 
          }, 
          "transport": "TRACE" 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I'm running an elasticsearch version of 6.5.2 on a 40 node cluster.
Any help is appreciated thanks.
I've tried changing the settings dynamically.As per my understanding shouldn't it suppose to give trace logs for transport level and warn logs for everything else?

Answer (score 1):

For Transport you may want to specify include field

```
"transient" : {
  "transport.tracer.include" : "*",
```

For search/index WARN logs please specify WARN time

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html
```